# Suppose there is a branch of the logarithm on a simply connected region $U$, when do we have the formula $\log z = \log r + i \theta$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, riemann-surfaces, multivalued-functions

I am following Stein and Shakarchi on Complex analysis. In a [previous thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3276288/128323), I learnt that if $U$ is a simply connected region with $1 \in U$ and $0 \not \in U$, then there is a branch of the logarithm on $U$.

I have the following two questions:

- I have learnt that on the principal branch of the logarithm, we have the formula $\log z = \log |z| + i \mathrm{arg}(z)$. But from the derivation, it seems to me it should be valid on $U$. Is this correct? If it is false, what would a good alternative formula be?
- If $1 \not\in U$, what would the formula become then?

Comment: You didn't define $arg(z)$. To make it well-defined say it is $\Bbb{R/2\pi Z}$ valued so that $\log z$ is $\Bbb{C/2i\pi Z}$ valued and there is now only one analytic group isomorphism $\log : \Bbb{C}^* \to\Bbb{C/2i\pi Z}$

Comment: And as @reuns says above, $\arg z$ is not a real number, so that it’s not clear how to add it to the real number $\log r$.